# Bios update on HP ProBook 4540s

Tags: bios

I am planning to update my bios on my HP ProBook 4540s running Windows 10.
I was wondering if it was safe to do that.
Afterwards I will enable virtualization.

Comment: Just make sure you have an UPS while doing it, because in case of a power cut off, your motherboard won’t work for ever again.

Comment: @Valay_17 unfortunately I don't have one.

Comment: The machine is a Pro Book with a battery so you do not need a UPS. Just make sure (as per my answer) that the Battery is fully charged before proceeding. That will work fine.

Comment: @John Even in case of laptops/probooks, while the bios update, the system asks you to connect to an AC source.

Comment: Yes. I noted that in my answer

Comment: Bios updates can be hazardous and brick a PC for many reasons out of your control, you are best to never update a bios unless this is the only way to solve a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine to update the BIOS. I do regular BIOS updates on my own and client machines without issue.

Updating the BIOS has nothing to do with Virtualization. Start in BIOS and go to the CPU settings and see if you can enable Virtualization and VT-x.  If you can, then (a) you have set Virtualization and (b) you can still update BIOS.

Note: Laptop practice is to have a fully charged battery prior to the update and be connected to AC power during the update.

Comment: Did you get VT-x working?  Did you update BIOS?